# Cognito UsernameExistsException when creating user from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Whenever I try to create a user using the cognito user pool web ui, I get the "UsernameExistsException" even though I only have 1/2 user(s) in my pool.
I tried switching devices and it worked to create another user and the stopped working again. All my alias attributes are unique so I'm not sure what else to do.

For me to be able to create multiple users using the UI.